# log4j category

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following on my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger = debug, stdout, fileLog

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.fileLog = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileLog.File = C:/logs/services.log
log4j.appender.fileLog.MaxFileSize = 256MB
log4j.appender.fileLog.MaxBackupIndex = 32
#Category: ConsultaDados
log4j.category.ConsultaDados=ConsultaDados
log4j.appender.ConsultaDados=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ConsultaDados.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ConsultaDados.layout.ConversionPattern={%t} %d - [%p] %c: %m %n
log4j.appender.ConsultaDados.file=C:/logs/consulta.log
log4j.appender.ConsultaDados.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm
```

And im creating my logger with :

```
myLogger = Logger.getLogger("ConsultaDados");
```

But this doesnt log my calls to the file. they get thrown into the rootLogger

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to finish this thread, the real issue was that the first value on your category line should have been a log level.   So, as you correctly discovered, changing :

**log4j.category.ConsultaDados=ConsultaDados**

to

**log4j.category.ConsultaDados=info,ConsultaDados**

worked properly.   As an FYI, you could have also changed the line to

**log4j.category.ConsultaDados=,ConsultaDados**

which would have caused you to inherit the logging level from the root logger.

Comment: category has been deprecated and replaced with logger.

Answer (score 10):

First, your category is not mapped to an appender, second *ConsultaDadosEORI* doesn't match any category.

Here is a sample :

```
log4j.appender.YOUR_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.YOUR_APPENDER.File=${SYSTEM_PROPEY_WITH_LOGGER_FOLDER}/log_file.log
log4j.appender.YOUR_APPENDER.Append=true
log4j.appender.YOUR_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.YOUR_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.YOUR_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.YOUR_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %p %c - %m %n
log4j.category.**YOUR_PACKAGE**=**INFO,YOUR_APPENDER** 
log4j.additivity.**YOUR_PACKAGE**=true or false
```

Comment: That was a misstype, only thing i dont understand is why do you say my category isn't mapped to an appender. since i have :
log4j.category.ConsultaDados=ConsultaDados

Comment: Ups, my mistake. I was confused by the fact that you defined a category before you defined the appender. Maybe this is the problem, I've always declared the appender and then use it.

Comment: well it worked =D, but i think the real trick was to put the LEVEL in it too