# Log4j Logging for custom Log levels in Java

Tags: java, log4j

I have written class for custom logging level i.e. `INIT`

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;

public class InitLoggingLevel extends Level {

    public static final String INITLOGGING_LEVEL = "INITLOGGING";
    public static final Level INIT_LOGGING = new InitLoggingLevel(
        DEBUG_INT - 4, INITLOGGING_LEVEL, 7);

    protected InitLoggingLevel(int level, String levelStr, int syslogEquivalent){
        super(level, levelStr, syslogEquivalent);
    }
}
```

Now what are changes I need to make in `log4j.properties` and how I am going to use this `INIT` logging level in My Java class?

Answer (score 3):

You have to:

1. Override the method `toLevel(String logArgument)` like this:

   ```
   public static Level toLevel(String logArgument) {
       if (logArgument != null && logArgument.toUpperCase().equals("INITLOGGING")) {
           return INIT_LOGGING;
       }
       return (Level) toLevel(logArgument);
   }
   ```
2. Write a configuration line in the log4j.properties like this:

   `log4j.logger.[MY_CATEGORY]=INITLOGGING#your-package.InitLoggingLevel`

That's all!

P.S.: The '#' syntax is described in [`org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/helpers/OptionConverter.html#toLevel(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.log4j.Level)) source class.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %c:%L - %m%n
log4j.category.YOUR_PACKAGE=INFO,YOUR_PACKAGE.InitLoggingLevel
```

or can view [log4j category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906292/log4j-category) 
or http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-how-to-send-log-messages-to-different-log-files/

Comment: i was asking for changes in log4j.properties to have logging level as INIT in logger.

Comment: log4j.category.com.impact.qtl12.commons=INIT,com.impact.qtl12.commons.InitLoggingLevel                                                                         like this , and how i am going to execute this in java class like for normal logger we do : logger.WARN so how can i have INIT level just by doing  logger.INIT or something else

Answer (score 0):

It can be like this :

```
 <category  name="xxx" additivity="false">
           <priority class="your class" value="info"/>
           <appender-ref ref="xxxlog"/>
        </category>
```

Comment: i was asking for log4j.properties

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you already figured it out, but I found the following article, which helped me.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/How_to_add_a_security_log_level_in_log4j

The new level is printed with the expected log tag, but log4j will not recognize the new level in my property file. I will see, what I can do about that.